# Uikit 3 Load more jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with Uikit 3 Grid and jQuery and `load more` function.
The load more script is based on:
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/load-more-single-button/

The button hides after load other 3 DIV´s, here is the code pen:
https://codepen.io/joomlaplates/pen/BapvQre

BTW: That happens only when masonry is activated in Uikit: `<div uk-grid="masonry: true">...</div>`

I would really appriciate some help..
Thanks Peter

Comment: Amazing, omg so easy.

Comment: Thank you so much, greatings. Have a nice day

Comment: Hi Pete, did you solve the issue?

Comment: Please add code block to the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have to be honest, I don't use Uikit much, but inspecting your example code I noticed that Uikit forces you the height of the div contents based on the width of the screen.

so, to solve, just bypass that rule via CSS .. :)

```
  .contents{
    height: auto!important;
  }
```

and below I leave you a small demo of the fix .. :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .contents{
        height: auto!important;
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.6.20/dist/css/uikit.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.5.2/minty/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.6.20/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* Button Load more - v1.0.0 - 2018-02-28
     * Copyright (c) 2018 NTTPS; */
    
    (function ($) {
      $.fn.btnLoadmore = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            showItem: 6
            , whenClickBtn: 3
            , textBtn: 'Loadmore ...'
            , classBtn: ''
            , setCookies: false
            , delayToScroll: 2000,
            
          }
          , options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        
        this.each(function () {
          
          var $this = $(this)
            , $childrenClass = $($this.children());
          
          // Get Element Of contents to hide
          $childrenClass.hide(); // nascondi tutti gli elementi
          
          //Show Element from Options
          $childrenClass.slice(0, defaults.showItem)
            .show(); // mostra il primo
          
          //Show Button when item in contents != 0
          if ($childrenClass.filter(":hidden")
            .length > 0) {
            $this.after('<button type="button" class="btn-loadmore ' + defaults.classBtn + '">' + defaults.textBtn + '</button>')
          }
          
          $(document).on('click', '.btn-loadmore', function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $childrenClass.filter(':hidden').slice(0, defaults.whenClickBtn).slideDown();
              if ($childrenClass.filter(":hidden").length == 0) {
                  $(".btn-loadmore").fadeOut('slow');
              }
              scrollDown();
          });
          
          function scrollDown() {
            $('html, body')
              .animate({
                scrollTop: $childrenClass.filter(":visible")
                  .last()
                  .offset()
                  .top
              }, defaults.delayToScroll);
          }
        });
        
        
        
      }
    }(jQuery));
    
    
    $(document)
      .ready(function () {
        
        $('.contents')
          .btnLoadmore({
            
            showItem: 3,
            
            whenClickBtn: 3,
            
            textBtn: 'Load more...',
            
            classBtn: 'btn btn-danger'
            
          });
        
      });
    
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div style="max-width:800px;margin-top:20px; margin:0 auto">
      <div class="contents uk-child-width-1-2@s uk-child-width-1-3@m" uk-grid="masonry: true">
        <div>
          <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle" style="height: 100px">Item</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle" style="height: 130px">Item</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle" style="height: 150px">Item</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          
          <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle" style="height: 160px">Item</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle" style="height: 120px">Item</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle" style="height: 140px">Item</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle" style="height: 200px">Item</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle" style="height: 180px">Item</div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle" style="height: 140px">Item</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Hi again, 
but how to remove the css heigh:auto after everything is loaded

Comment: or? if it creates unwanted conflicts within the page you can always assign it a dedicated CSS class .. :)